# How can I insert a row in between every other row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |

and a row that looks like: [1,2]

How can I insert this row in between rows 1 & 2, 2 & 3, and so on?

In other words, how do I insert a row every other row in a dataframe?

Comment: Add expected output and your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add [1,2] in the table that contains only 1,2 then you can repeat those values:

```
df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(2)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Otherwise if there is different value you can try:

```
df.index=[x for x in range (len(df)*2) if x%2!=0]
for x in range (2,(len(df)*2)+2):
    if x%2==0:
        df.loc[x]=[2,3]

df=df.sort_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    a   b
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   1   2
4   2   3
5   1   2
6   2   3
```

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of a mathematical problem about a hotel with infinite number of rooms.

But here is the solution, we multiply the index by 2, and concatenate a new dataframe with odd indexes. Then sort by index.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

rows = [[3,4]]

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""a    b
1   2
1   2
1   2"""), sep="\s+")

nrows = df.shape[0] - 1
df.index = df.index*2

new_df = pd.DataFrame(rows * nrows, columns=["a", "b"])
new_df.index = new_df.index*2 + 1

>>> pd.concat([df, new_df]).sort_index()
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  1  2
3  3  4
4  1  2
```