# How to add multiple rows in dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe(df) like below (there are more rows actually).

|  | number |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 21 |
| 1 | 35 |
| 2 | 467 |
| 3 | 965 |
| 4 | 2754 |
| 5 | 34r |
| 6 | 5743 |
| 7 | 841 |
| 8 | 8934 |
| 9 | 275 |

I want to insert multiple 6 rows in between rows for example I want to get random 6 values within range of index 0 and 1 and add these 6 rows between index 0 and 1.
Same goes to index 1 and 2, 2 and 3 and so forth until the end.

```
np.linspace(df["number"][0], df["number"][1],8)
```

Is there a function or any other method to generate 6 additional rows between all existing 9 rows so therefore the final number of rows will be not 9 but 64 rows (after adding 54 rows)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I insert a row in between every other row in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219545/how-can-i-insert-a-row-in-between-every-other-row-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: no... I need to use all the values of df to create every 6 rows which will be in between designated rows.

Comment: In your example, you need to create random values, so the actual values of the dataframe don't matter. That can be easily accomplished with the first answer to my suggested duplicate: just change the fixed `df.loc[x]=[2,3]` by `df.loc[x]=foo_function()`. And you need to fix how it iterates so you call your functions six times for every one row.

Comment: Note that an obvious brute force solution would be to create a list out of your df and intercalate it's values with the random ones. So if you need the new values to be based on the actual ones, please add the rational to your post.

Comment: So the new 6 rows between row 0 and row 1 should have random numbers between 21 and 35, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```py
from random import uniform

def rng_numbers(row):
    left, right = row.iat[0], row.iat[1]
    n = left
    if pd.isna(right):
        return [n]
    if right < left:
        left, right = right, left
    return [n] + [uniform(left, right) for _ in range(6)]

df["number"] = (
    pd.concat([df["number"], df["number"].shift(-1)], axis=1)
    .apply(rng_numbers, axis=1)
)
df = df.explode("number", ignore_index=True)
```

- First create a dataframe with 2 columns that form the interval boundaries: the `number` column and `number` column shifted 1 forth.
- Then `.apply` the function `rng_numbers` to the rows of the new dataframe: `rng_numbers` first sorts the interval boundaries and then returns a list that starts with the resp. item from column `number` and then `num_rows` many random numbers in the interval. In the last row the left boundary is `NaN` (due to the `.shift(-1)`): in this case the function returns the list without the random numbers.
- Then `.explode` `df` on the new column `number`.

You could do something similar with NumPy, which is probably faster:

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng()

limits = pd.concat([df["number"], df["number"].shift(-1)], axis=1)
left = limits.min(axis=1).values.reshape(-1, 1)
right = limits.max(axis=1).values.reshape(-1, 1)
df["number"] = (
    pd.Series(df["number"].values.reshape(len(df), 1).tolist())
    + pd.Series(rng.uniform(left, right, size=(len(df), 6)).tolist())
)
df["number"].iat[-1] = df["number"].iat[-1][:1]
df = df.explode("number", ignore_index=True)
```